# How to pull private docker image from docker to new machine

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a new machine with a docker engine. I want to pull down a private docker image from docker.com.

I can pull down any public docker image, no problem.

```
klas@dockerengine:~$ docker pull nginx
latest: Pulling from nginx

39bb80489af7: Pull complete
df2a0347c9d0: Pull complete
[...]
```

But my private image fails:

```
klas@dockerengine:~$ docker pull mellbourn/privaterepo
Pulling repository mellbourn/privaterepo
FATA[0002] Error: image mellbourn/privaterepo:latest not found
```

What should I do?

It may have to do with SSH, but I know very little about SSH.

Comment: Did you run docker login?

Comment: @AdrianMouat Doh! No I did not. Now it works.

Comment: ok :) Added this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `docker login` before you can access private repositories.